# How to set owner ID on a directory and it's children

Tags: unix, file-permissions, file-ownership

the command `chmod g+s .` would set the group ID on the current directory, so that all files created within this directory would belong to the directory's group user, and not to the user that created the file.

What is the command to achieve the same result, but this time with the files/directories ownership?

What I'm trying to achieve is that all files moved to or created in `/var/data/www` belong to `www-data www-data` (onwer and group). `chmod g+s .` executed in `www/` does the trick for the group, but I want to set the owner automatically, too - regardless of who uploaded the files.

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow. Perhaps it would be a better fit at http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting uid on a directory would not enforce new files to be owned by the owner of this directory. They will still be owned by the user that creates them.

So consequently `chomd g+s .` would enforce files/directories group ownership, but `chomd u+s .` would not have the same effect for the owner.

This is true on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I am always using

```
chown -R user:group .
```

to change files in directory and subdirectories

Comment: Hi, that will work, but it'd have to be executed each time. With `chown g+s .` the process is automatic. Whenever files are added, they're group ID is automatically set to the parent directory's group ID.

Comment: I've made  a mistake, it's all about `chmod g+s`. I've now corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system and file system. There exists different kinds of extended attributes and ACLs. OSX `xattr`, Linux `setfattr`, etc.

On some systems set-uid-bit set on directory, enforces new files to be owned by the owner of the directory.